# Is there a way to initialize a list outside the loop, have it deleted and reuse in dart?

Tags: list, dart

I have here 2 functions,

```
List<List<int>> inputmatrix() {
  print("Please insert the number of rows of this matrix?"); int k = int.parse(stdin.readLineSync());
  print("Please insert the number of column of this matrix?"); int q = int.parse(stdin.readLineSync());
  List<List<int>> d = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < k; i++) {
    List<int> d1 = [];
    for (var j = 0; j < q; j++) {
      print("Please insert element [${i + 1},${j + 1}]");
      int a = int.parse(stdin.readLineSync());
      d1.add(a);
    }
    d.add(d1);
  }
  return d;
}

List<List<int>> inputmatrix1() {
  print("Please insert the number of rows of this matrix?"); int k = int.parse(stdin.readLineSync());
  print("Please insert the number of column of this matrix?"); int q = int.parse(stdin.readLineSync());
  List<List<int>> d = [];
  List<int> d1 = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < k; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < q; j++) {
      print("Please insert element [${i + 1},${j + 1}]");
      int a = int.parse(stdin.readLineSync());
      d1.add(a);
    }
    d.add(d1);
    d1.clear();
  }
  return d;
}
```

but inputmatrix() does work, and inputmatrix1() doesn't. When array d1 is cleared in inputmatrix1(), so does the value of that in d. And yet, when I pasted the declaration of d1 inside the loop, it works. Could anyone tell me why Dart behaves like this? Dart returns by value, but if that's the case then inputmatrix() shouldn't work either. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do:

```
d.add(d1);
```

You are adding a reference to the list which `d1` points at. This is fine in `inputmatrix` since you are creating a new list for each iteration in your first for-loop and points to this new list with `d1`.

But in `inputmatrix1` you are reusing the same list instance and keep a reference to this list in `d1`. Since you are then calling `.clean()` on this same list instance it will be changed for all who are referring to the same list instance (like your `d` list of lists).

Again, `d1` is just a reference to a list and when you are calling `add()` you are adding the value of the reference to the list. But this value should be seen as a pointer to a list instance and not the list itself.

About the question I don't know what issue you are trying to solve since `inputmatrix` seems like the correct way to do what you are trying to achieve. There is nothing wrong declaring variables in a more restricted scope.

Comment: I see. So it's adding the instance of a list, not the value of said list. Thank you for your help. :)

Comment: May I ask that how do you know all this stuff? Is there a book on OOP that I should be reading?

Comment: Well, I do have a master degree in software development and have followed the Dart language for 7+ years so this is properly the main reason I know stuff like this. But I can recommend reading the language tour: https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour if you want some general knowledge about the language. I don't know any good resources for general OOP knowledge. :)

Comment: I see. I'm actually in college, studying to get my Bachelor in I.T. I feel like I should know this though.